# Rounding zero with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to use `siunitx` to format numbers. In the following MWE I confused why the "format" of the two numbers is different. Is there a way to automatically format 0.00000 as 0.00 just like 1.000000 is shown as 1.00?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\num[round-precision = 2, round-mode = places]{1.000000} \\
\num[round-precision = 2, round-mode = places]{0.000000}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cant confirm your founding. Both numbers has the same number of decimal digits (2).

Comment: I get "1.00" and "0.00" as expected. There were lots of updates after the v3 release. I run `2021-06-22 v3.0.15` (*edit* just updated to `2021-06-24 v3.0.16`, same expected result). What version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue in the v3.0.0 release, was reported as [issue #477](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/477) and was fixed in commit [8a05d7](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/8a05d7603d6137efb9fc42e315c4f65ba223bcdd). This was part of v3.0.12, released on 2021-06-09.

Comment: Using 3.1.4 it does not work in an `S` column of table, though.

Comment: @Adam I am nor sure what you mean: could you post a new question with an example of the issue?

Comment: Yes, but it would be more of a bug report, not at question. I meant rounding 0.0000 does not work as expected in an S column in a table with `round-mode=figures`.